# Error: "Tried to read the folder contents...but could not"

Tags: cache, error

I'm stumped on this one, for the longest time when I clicked the "Clear Caches" button in the CP, everything seemed to be ok. But I recently checked the craft.log after noticing things didn't seem to be clearing out after all. There was this error:

2016-02-16 09:25:11

```
Level   error
Category    application
Message Tried to read the folder contents of /home/[company-name]/craft/storage/runtime/temp/, but could not.
2016-02-16 09:25:11

Level   error
Category    application
Message Tried to read the folder contents of /home/[company-name]/craft/storage/runtime/assets/, but could not.
2016-02-16 09:25:11

Level   error
Category    application
Message Tried to read the folder contents of /home/[company-name]/craft/storage/runtime/cache/, but could not.
```

The permissions are as follows:

```
/craft 755
  /storage 777
     /runtime 777
        /temp 777
           empty
        /assets 777
           empty
        /cache 777
           09f795de983f214fb0e9188dd884ec27.bin 664
           +another 26 of the same - these don't clear when I click the clear cache button
```

I tried changing the 664 to 777 but it reverted itself back to 664.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Do those folders actually exist at the time you use the "Clear Caches" tool?  They are dynamically created as needed, so it could be more of an informational message than a permissions one.

Comment: They do exist, although temp didn't have anything in it. Nothing seems to disappear from the cache and assets (there's a handful of thumbs) folder when I use the "Clear Caches" Tool (it is supposed to...right? Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the 664 through SSH instead of manually. These three folders need the right permissions:

- craft/app/
- craft/config/
- craft/storage/

source: https://craftcms.com/docs/installing

Edit: Have you tried removing the content of the Cache?

Comment: Thanks for responding, if I delete the folder contents do I also have to clear out the database cache table as well (I wasn't sure if the two are 'connected')? Or can I just leave it at deleting the stuff in the folder?

Comment: I noticed the same error on the dev version of the site so I deleted the folder contents on there for testing, clicked around the site a bit, clicked the clear button again, but no dice. The same error still appeared. I double checked the folder permissions and all the subfolder permissions